# How can I share state between two objects rendered in different arrays in React using context and state?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-state

So I made this app that uses an array of objects to render data. I also categorize this data so it can be sorted into different arrays based on the category. Each object can have multiple categories, thus is listed between multiple arrays.

```
 {
    belongsTo: String,
    name: "Front Line Salvager I",
    description: "Complete Salvage or Deep Dive activities...",
    category: ['Deep Dive', 'Salvage'],
    completed: false,
    challengeIndex: Number,
    objectives: [...],
    reward: null,
    xp: "Challenger XP+",
    dust: null
  },
```

So this data will exist and be rendered in two arrays:

```
const activityChallenges = [
        {
            name: 'Deep Dive',
            challenges: []
        },
        {
            name: 'Salvage',
            challenges: []
        }
]
```

I use a custom context hook to create state for all the data. This solution worked great before I started sorting things into categories and everything rendered down the page without duplicates.

```
<section className='ChallengeCategory-Body' id={ChallengeCategoryContainerID}>
                {props.challenges.map((challenge) => {
                    let uuid = crypto.randomUUID();
                    return (
                        // Wrap the State Provider for Individual 
                        // Challenges and Pass Challenge Data 
                        // to Dispatch Initial State
                        <ChallengeProvider
                            key={uuid}
                            data={{ challenge }}
                        >
                            // React component to render data
                            <ChallengeCard
                                key={uuid}
                                // key={uuidv4()}
                                challengesRemainingID={challengesRemainingID}
                                togglerID={togglerID}
                                activityHeader={activityHeader}
                            />
                        </ChallengeProvider>
                    )
                })}
            </section>
```

So, I would like to know how to go about sharing state between two objects that are rendered in two different arrays, but are fundamentally the same data. Users can toggle the checkbox and set progress in the select box. The app  will update Boolean values for completed tasks. But I would like to have each instance of the object to sync when a user changes a select option or checkbox. This is an example of what I'm talking about on the rendered page[duplicate object data that does not share state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtgBF.jpg)

I tried using the same key and learned that's not at all how react will function if a same key is passed. Originally worked from local storage but I created a mongo database to sync between devices. I realistically should have made a document each object in these arrays their own document but didn't want to refactor the whole app

Answer (score 0):

Don't duplicate the array. Keep one source of truth. Just filter out the items that don't match the currently displayed category as you're iterating over this one array in the .map() calls in your components.